# How do i extract data from an DotNetOpenID AX attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth

Andrew Arnott has a post here about how to extract the attribute exchange extension data, from an OpenId proivder. Here's a snippet of the code :-

```
var fetch = openid.Response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();   
if (fetch != null)
{   
    IList<string> emailAddresses = fetch.GetAttribute
                                   (WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email).Values;   
    IList<string> fullNames = fetch.GetAttribute
                                   (WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName).Values;   
    string email = emailAddresses.Count > 0 ? emailAddresses[0] : null;   
    string fullName = fullNames.Count > 0 ? fullNames[0] : null;   
}
```

When i try to do the following...

```
fetch.GetAttribute(...)
```

I get a compile error. Basically, that doesn't exist. Is the only (read: proper) way to do this as follows...

```
fetch.Attribue[WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email].Values
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid my blog post was written for DotNetOpenId 2.x, but DotNetOpenAuth 3.x has a slightly different API for the AX extension and that's what you're running into.

What you came to is *close*, but not quite what you should have.  What you have would generate a `NullReferenceException` or `KeyNotFoundException` if the attribute isn't included in the response from the Provider.  Actually that might be a bug in my blog post too, unless DNOI 2.x was implemented differently I don't recall.

Anyway, here's what you should do to fish out an email address:

```
if (fetch.Attributes.Contains(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)) {
    IList<string> emailAddresses =
        fetch.Attributes[WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email].Values;
    string email = emailAddresses.Count > 0 ? emailAddresses[0] : null;
    // do something with email
}
```

If that seems laborious for just pulling out the email address, chalk it up to the complexity and flexibility of the AX extension itself.  Sorry about that.

Comment: You know, seeing how cumbersome the "right" code is to fetch a single AX value motivated me to add a helper method to the FetchResponse class.  It will be in v3.2.
http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/ticket/67

Comment: Yeah. i added an extension method which did this last night. I posted it in my another SO post. But you've added it which is all good :) my extension method passed in a params of keys, so i can extract the first value for the first key, in the key params :)

Comment: Also, will emailAddresses always return an instance? could it return NULL ?

Comment: the Values property always returns non-null, so emailAddresses will be non-null as well.