# How to get email, gender and username from Google OpenID Provider

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I Have made Login system using open ID Using the following code

```
<rp:OpenIdLogin runat="server" Identifier="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"   Visible="true" 
        ExampleUrl="" LabelText=" " RegisterText="Register"    ExamplePrefix=" " ID="OpenIdLogin1"  
        OnLoggedIn="OpenIdTextBox1_LoggedIn" RequestEmail="Require" RequestPostalCode="Request"></rp:OpenIdLogin>
```

It Takes the user to Google for authentication i only want to sotre the user Information like email ID and his Fullname and Sex to My DB

I have written the following code to retirve email from google bu nothing is retuernd

```
Imports System
Imports DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange
Partial Class Food
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Session("FetchResponse") Is Nothing) Then
            Return
        End If
        Dim fetchResponse As FetchResponse = CType(Session("FetchResponse"), FetchResponse)
        Email = fetchResponse.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
    End Sub

    Public Property Email() As String
        Get

        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

**Update**

I have used loginame to display the authenticated username but it displays
like this
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmQoYAeHRxYW0ZOcQ5VODMPWJQgPOAYkTs

how can i display actual email or username

Comment: Please work on your acceptance on your previous questions asked.

Comment: Dear check my profile carefully and give answer to my question plz i am in trouble due to open id

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get email from Google OpenID Provider (in VB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599252/how-to-get-email-from-google-openid-provider-in-vb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See duplicate question [How to get email from Google OpenID Provider (in VB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599252/how-to-get-email-from-google-openid-provider-in-vb) for the answer, with the addendum that:

You cannot get the Google user's *username* or gender.  You can get their email address and I think that's about it.  (Maybe their full name as well).  This is up to individual OpenID Providers and Google, like other large ones, has elected to provide minimal data on the user.

Comment: @Adeel you can get Gender by using this API...http://api.namsor.com/onomastics/api/json/gendre/John/Smith

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DotNetOpenAuth? Here is how I've done it

**Edit:** I added the code I have for OpenID Login. Basically you make a request to the OpenID provider and get a response from your request. If the request was successful you should have some information about your user but remember that different OpenID providers give different information regarding your users, some parameters might not be there even if you requested for them. My code is from an ASP.NET MVC application

```
public ActionResult OpenIDLogin(string loginIdentifier)
{
    var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    var response = openid.GetResponse();

    // If there is a response from the specified OpenID identifier we parse it and check it's status
    if (response != null)
    {
        //check the response status
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                var extensions = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
                var user = new User
                        {
                            extensions.FullName, 
                            extensions.Nickname, 
                            extensions.Email,
                            response.ClaimedIdentifier
                        };

                return View();

            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                // TODO

            case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                // TODO
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If there isn't a response then we need to create the request and add desired extensions
        var request = openid.CreateRequest(loginIdentifier);

        request.AddExtension
            (
                new ClaimsRequest()
                {
                    FullName = DemandLevel.Require,
                    Nickname = DemandLevel.Require,
                    Email = DemandLevel.Require,
                    Gender = DemandLevel.Require
                }
            );

        return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The method gets called twice; once when the request is first made and it falls in the "else" statement, and a second time when the response comes back and enters the "if" statement, creating the User. Hope this helps, and sorry that it's in C# but I don't know VB that well as to write it.

Comment: Can u tell me the compelte process of openid I will be verythankful to u because i am working on this for many days but dnt get success

Comment: No No dear i dnt using MVC i am using asp.net web forms Please tell me complete solution in steps for Web form i only want to display email address of user on my webpage

Comment: I'd be pretty much the same, just that instead of having this code in an "Action" you would have it in your "Page_Load" method and reference your page elements.

Comment: I want only to retirve the email and fullname of user an display it on page nothig else please only resolve my this issue i am in trouble

Comment: It looks like you are using version 3 of DotNetOpenAuth and it has changed from when I used it. Maybe this question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887748/how-do-i-extract-data-from-an-dotnetopenid-ax-attribute

Comment: I dnt get i am using asp.net 2.0 Dotnetopenid v3 please tell somthihg else