# How to get email from Google OpenID Provider (in VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

Salam to all
I am using the DotNetOpenAuth control for authentication from google. This is the code that I am using.

```
<rp:OpenIdLogin ID="OID" runat=server Identifier="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" RequestEmail="Require" ></rp:OpenIdLogin>
```

To get the response from the provider for the email ID I am using this code in the page load event of default.aspx

```
 Public Email As String = "N/A"

    Public FullName As String = "N/A"

    Public Country As String = "N/A"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim openid As OpenIdRelyingParty = New OpenIdRelyingParty
        Dim response = openid.GetResponse
        If (Not (response) Is Nothing) Then
            Select Case (response.Status)
                Case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated
                    Dim fetch = response.GetExtension
                    Dim email As String = String.Empty
                    If (Not (fetch) Is Nothing) Then
                        email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email)
                    End If
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, False)
            End Select
        End If


    End Sub
```

I am able be authenticated with google, but there is no response of the email id from google.
Please tell me what exactly I am missing that is causing this problem.

**Update**

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true"/>
  </configSections>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                    with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
```

Comment: Anyone Please give amswer to my question

Comment: You are authenticate with the Google means Google must be sending back you to your web-page? can you show the URL you are getting after you are being redirected back to to your page from Google

Comment: Goog is Returning this URL     https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmQoYAeHRxYW0ZOcQ5VODMPWJQgPOAYkTs

Comment: So what may be the problem according ur opinion

Comment: Sir Please Answer to my question

Comment: @user1109140, please don't bumb the question by asking another question. This question is only 8 hours old, it has 2 upvotes.  If anyone knows the answer, it will come.

Comment: Ok Sorry to bumb but NoOne knows my problem ? Its Amazing or a challenge for Stack users

Comment: @user1109140 - the answers on this site are from random people on the Internet who have experience in a topic. Most of us expect you to do some work on your own, and provide enough information to answer the question. In this case, you need to tell us exactly what Google returns to your. We're not going to guess, and we're not going to run your code.

Comment: Also: posting the same question multiple times will not get you answers faster, it will simply annoy the people who see them, and get your questions flagged for the moderators to delete. Please read the FAQ before posting another question: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Ok Sorry to post my question again .and i have already tell u that google is not returning anything.If used the asp.net loginname control on my web page then it display the follwign url    "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?   id=AItOawmQoYAeHRxYW0ZOcQ5VODMPWJQgPOAYkTs"  So now tell me how can i display the actual email address of the user on my webpage

Comment: Sir Please Now answer to my question

Comment: Patience, @user1109140.  Most answers can take a few days go answer.  I have the answer, but I'm tempted not to post it given your spamming this post with so many pointless comments.

Comment: Your question looks like it has incorrectly copied code.  Your `GetExtension` call takes no arguments.  That shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely missing the appropriate "behavior" in your web.config file.  Please study this page and apply it to your site: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Enhancements

Also, when using this behavior, you should be looking for the `ClaimsResponse` extension in the positive authentication response rather than `FetchResponse`.

As a side note, you have a lot of boilerplate code in your code-behind's `Page_Load` method that you don't need.  The `OpenIdControl` you're using has a `LoggedIn` method that does most of what you're doing here (it gets you all the way to the body of your `Case` block.

Comment: I have already this setting in my web.config but no difference to my problem i update my web.config in qustion please see it

Comment: The Logged Inn event will be used in login.aspx where the openid control is being used.But How can the default page get the response from google and display the email of authenticated username

Comment: Arnot   According to my code how can and where can should use claim response

Comment: Is default.aspx the page with the `OpenIdLogin` control on it?